# How do I limit a user's scopes when granting an OAuth2 token?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

In Spring Security OAuth2, I can limit the scopes that a client is permitted to request by configuring the `ClientDetails`. However, in addition to limiting by client, I also want to limit the scopes available to individual users; for example, a user should only be able to access the `admin.forceLogout` scope when holding `ROLE_ADMIN`.

I don't want to directly map user authorities to scopes, as `checkUserScopes` does; instead, I want to run custom logic to inspect and modify the scopes associated with a particular token grant. What's the best way to do that?

I see two possibilities, neither of which looks ideal:

- Provide a `TokenEnhancer` that modifies the token after issuance. This seems like it's intended more for including additional information, such as audience claims, than for rewriting the already-available scopes. In particular, this runs after the `confirm_access` step.
- Provide a custom `OAuth2RequestFactory`. At a minimum, this involves duplicating a lot of security-sensitive logic. Overriding `checkUserScopes()` seems like the perfect place to put the custom policy, but it's private, and the only override point is on the entire `createTokenRequest()`.

Is there a better way to do this sort of "intersection" filtering, or are these the two options?